# Knockout list binding with a checkbox and click handle

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

Here is my jsfiddle for illustration:
http://jsfiddle.net/hawaii/gN6CT/10/

I have a list of json objects that I want to bind into an ul using jquery templates, in each li I have a checkbox for each item, together with the item details. The way I want it to work is:

When user click on the checkbox, the item will be updated into a selected list ( Got this working)

When user click on the details of the items, the item will be the selected one and I will display all the details on the right. That's why I am putting the items details inside an  element.

As you can see from the fiddle, it isn't working the way I want it to work, click binding is called even when the viewModel first applied, and when I click on the checkbox, it calling the click event as well.

Can you knockout gurus help me on this please.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see a couple of small things:

1- you should not use both the `checked` and `value` binding on the same element.  The `value` binding will attach event handlers, as will the `checked` binding.  In this case, you just want to ensure that the `value` attribute is set and not handle any events, so you can do: `checked:$parent.checkedPeople, attr: { value: Id }`

2- the click binding expects a reference to a function and not the result of a function being executed.  So, you were passing: `click: $parent.selectPerson(Id())`.  This will execute the function during binding and try to bind against the result (which would not be effective, unless the result was actually a function).  An alternative would be to do: `click: function() { $parent.selectPerson(Id()); }`.  However, it is ugly to have anonymous functions in the markup, so a better choice would be to simply do: `click: $parent.selectPerson`.  The current `$data` will be passed along as the first argument and you can read the `Id` off of it.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gN6CT/11/

Comment: I'm working on a different problem, but was just bumping into the problem you identify in point #1.  Thanks!